space of $k$ times continuously differentiable function is dense in sobolev space $W^{k,p}$
I am solving some exercises on proving Banach Spaace. A question is given in the following way:

For $1\le p<\infty$ and $k=1,2,...$, let $W^{k,p}=\{x\in C^{k-1}([a,b]): x^{k-1}$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ and $x^{(k)}\in L^p([a,b])\}$. Define $$\Vert x \Vert _{k,p}=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\int_a^b|x(j)|^pdm\right)^{1/p}$$ for $x\in W^{k,p}.$ Then $W^{k,p}$ is a Banach space, known as the Sobolev Space of order $(k,p)$ on $[a,b]$ The completion of $C^k([a,b])$ with the norm $\Vert \bullet \Vert_{k,p}$ can be identified with $W^{k,p}.$

I must confess that I am unfamiliar with Sobolev spaces and this is my first time in Functional Analysis. I have struggled a lot and completed the outlines of proving the space $W^{k,p}$ as a complete normed linear space. I observed some steps written using the concept of weak derivatives which I also don't know. Now, I want to show $W^{k,p}$ as a completion of $C^k([a,b])$. I know it is enough to show $C^k([a,b])$ as a dense set in $W^{k,p}$ w.r.t. the norm $\Vert \bullet \Vert_{k,p}.$ For this, I will take an $\epsilon$- ball in $W^{k,p}$ around a fixed point $x\in W^{k,p}- C^k([a,b])$ and try to show a point $y\in C^k([a,b])$ inside the $\epsilon$-ball. But, how to choose this $y$? Please help me, if I am wrong, then correct me. Thank you beforehand!!!

The weak derivative is actually usually part of the definition of Sobolev spaces ... what course are you following ? Usually, one takes $f_n = \rho_n * f$ where $\rho_n$ is a smooth approximation of unity (for example $\rho_n(x) = n,\rho(x,n)$ with $\rho\in C^\infty_c$ but then it is better to extend to the whole space first)

@LL3.14, I am reading Functional Analysis now, and I got the proof of $W^{k,p}$ as Banach Space from the book L.C. Evans Partial Differential Equation.
